# How to configure phpmailer to send mails with proxies?

Tags: php, email, proxy, smtp, phpmailer

**How can i use proxies to send smtp mails using PHPmailer?
The proxy format is: proxy/port/user/password
I am using following code to send email:**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'C:/xampp/php/pear/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'C:/xampp/php/pear/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
$mail->isSMTP();                                    
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = "test@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "password";                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->From = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";

$mail->addAddress("address@yahoo.com", "name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Mail Subject";
$mail->Body = "Something";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

**I tried with socat had no success since socat cannot be installed on my server,i also tried with curl but had no success.**

I'm also aware that phpmailer has no explicit SMTP proxy support.

Also guide me if there is a substitute for PHPMailer that can use proxy, in case proxies can't be configured for PHPMailer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is [the same question as was asked on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2197) recently.

The short answer is that you can't. Not because PHPMailer doesn't support it, but because proxying SMTP doesn't really exist in any practical sense because of its disconnected, async, store-and-forward nature. It's completely unlike HTTP in this respect. You have two alternatives:

1. Use a TCP proxy. You specify the proxy host IP as your mail server, and it forwards the traffic. This is completely transparent to PHPMailer, and so does not require any specific support, but you are likely to run into TLS issues.
2. Use an SMTP relay. Send to a "nearby" mail server (usually referred to as a "smarthost") which then deals with onward delivery for you. This is probably what you want. Again, PHPMailer doesn't care about your relaying arrangements here as you simply deliver to the smarthost as usual, so no specific support is required.

The reason an "SMTP proxy" can't really work is because there is no guarantee that an SMTP server can make an onward delivery. It may require literally days of waiting and retrying to deliver a message, and this means that the proxy needs to implement everything an SMTP server does, turning it into an SMTP relay.

There *are* SMTP proxies, but they are typically only ever used in high-availability environments, such as in SMTP front-end load balancers, where immediate onward delivery is essentially guaranteed to be possible, so the proxy needs no local storage or queuing abilities. That's probably not what you're looking for.

If you want more than that you need to say exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, why, and how.